# Use bulk insert to upload a .csv file to sql table including a unique identifier

Tags: asp.net, sql, bulkinsert

I need to upload a .csv file to a sql table through an asp.net upload control. I have the sql bulk insert command ready but I need to have it so it assigns each record that is uploaded from the .csv file a uniqueidentifier (guid) automatically. This isnt included in the .csv file. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can set your table up to use a default `NEWID()` so that the unique identifier is added automatically when a record is inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE MyUniqueTable
   (UniqueColumn   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      DEFAULT NEWID(),
   Characters      VARCHAR(10) )
GO
INSERT INTO MyUniqueTable(Characters) VALUES ('abc')
GO
```

When you do your bulk insert, each row will have a unique identifier added to it.